# woocommerce show attribute description when selecting a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out a way to display custom text based on the users selection of the variable product.

The attribute is 'pricing' and the tag is deposit - which I've added a text description to when adding the attribute. So I'm trying to make this text appear when the user selects 'deposit'

But the code I'm using in 'content-single-product.php' is displaying the text all the time no matter what variable is selected or not.

```
<?php $my_taxonomy = 'pa_pricing'; 

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $my_taxonomy ); 

echo term_description($terms[0]->term_id, $my_taxonomy); 
 ?>
```

I only want the text to be displayed after the user has selected pricing 'deposit' Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on php, but as you declare your $my_taxonomy to be *the text* "pa_pricing"

So, for starters, that should be something like

```
$my_taxonomy = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_pricing');
```

That might help you?  As for the rest of your question, I'd really like an answer on that one too!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains a way of doing this:

http://blueskysessions.com/2014/03/31/woocommerce-display-dynamic-content-per-the-selected-product-variation/

The poster modifies variable.php - probably a better place to insert the code.

If you found another way, do please share it here.